# Возвращение значений таблицы

Tags: c#, oledb, sql

Здравствуйте!

Вопрос такой, как вернуть значения выполненного sql-запроса, присвоить поля текущей записи в компоненты формы?

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:/BD.mdb");
OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
com.Connection = conn;
com.CommandText = "Select * from "+comboBox1.Text;
conn.Open();
adap.SelectCommand = com;
adap.Fill(ds);            
dt = ds.Tables[0];
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
conn.Close();
```

Присвоить значения текущей записи, к примеру, текстовым полям...

```
this.textBox1.text = ?????????
this.textBox2.text = ?????????
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
var row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
this.TextBox1.Text = row["SomeColumn"].ToString();
```

Рекомендую почитать про `BindingSource`, чтобы понять, как в .NET можно осуществлять декларативную привязку данных.